# How to eliminate zeros after doing tensor product of two sparse matrices in scipy?

Tags: python, scipy

I want to do tensor product of two sparse matrices in scipy. And I use the following code

```
sig1 = csc_matrix(np.array([[0, 1],[1, 0]]))
sig2 = csc_matrix(np.array([[0 , -1],[1 , 0]]))
print(sparse.kron(sig1, sig2))
```

However, I get the following result

`(2, 0)        0
 (3, 0)        1
 (2, 1)        -1
 (3, 1)        0
 (0, 2)        0
 (1, 2)        1
 (0, 3)        -1
 (1, 3)        0`
which means that the sparse matrix allocates memories also for (2,0) (3,1) (0,2) (1,3) entries even if these entries are all zeros as well. This is definitely a waste of memory especially after I do the tensor product for multiple times. Is there a way to avoid it in scipy or eliminate these entries after the computation? Thank you very much!

Comment: In this case there are a number of zeros because the return format is BSR, block sparse.  If you specify `csc` or `coo` format, you won't see the 0s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [142]: sig1 = sparse.csc_matrix(np.array([[0, 1],[1, 0]]))
     ...: sig2 = sparse.csc_matrix(np.array([[0 , -1],[1 , 0]]))
```

We see the 0s because the return format is Block Sparse Row:

```
In [143]: M=sparse.kron(sig1,sig2)
In [144]: M
Out[144]: 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 8 stored elements (blocksize = 2x2) in Block Sparse Row format>
In [145]: M.A
Out[145]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0, -1],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  0],
       [ 0, -1,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=int64)
```

If we specify another format, we don't see the 0s:

```
In [146]: M=sparse.kron(sig1,sig2, format='csc')
In [147]: M
Out[147]: 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
In [148]: M.A
Out[148]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0, -1],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  0],
       [ 0, -1,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=int64)
```

The `kron` code says it uses BSR because `sig2` is relatively dense.  The attributes of the BSR version are:

```
In [150]: M=sparse.kron(sig1,sig2)
In [151]: M.indptr
Out[151]: array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
In [152]: M.indices
Out[152]: array([1, 0], dtype=int32)
In [153]: M.data
Out[153]: 
array([[[ 0, -1],
        [ 1,  0]],

       [[ 0, -1],
        [ 1,  0]]], dtype=int64)
```

Attributes for a `csr` equivalent:

```
In [158]: M1=sparse.kron(sig1,sig2, 'csr')
In [159]: M1.indptr
Out[159]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int32)
In [160]: M1.indices
Out[160]: array([3, 2, 1, 0], dtype=int32)
In [161]: M1.data
Out[161]: array([-1,  1, -1,  1], dtype=int64)
```

`data` is smaller, but `indices` and `indptr` larger.  Differences may be more pronounced if the matrices are much larger.

Comment: Thank you very much for your wonderful answer! A follow up question, if I want to do tensor product many times as well as do some e.g. matrix multiplication with the matrix but try to use as little memory as possible, which one do you recommend?